# Call a Ruby function from the command line

Tags: ruby, command-line

How can I directly call a Ruby function from the command line?

Imagine, I would have this script *test.rb*:

```
class TestClass
    def self.test_function(some_var)
        puts "I got the following variable: #{some_var}"
    end
end
```

If this script is run from the command line (`ruby test.rb`), nothing happens (as intended).

Is there something like `ruby test.rb TestClass.test_function('someTextString')`?

I want to get the following output: `I got the following variable: someTextString`.

Answer (score 102, accepted):

First the name of the class needs to start with a capital letter, and since you really want to use a static method, the function name definition needs to start with `self.`.

```
class TestClass
    def self.test_function(someVar)
        puts "I got the following variable: " + someVar
    end
end
```

Then to invoke that from the command line you can do:

```
ruby -r "./test.rb" -e "TestClass.test_function 'hi'"
```

If you instead had `test_function` as an instance method, you'd have:

```
class TestClass
    def test_function(someVar)
        puts "I got the following variable: " + someVar
    end
end
```

then you'd invoke it with:

```
ruby -r "./test.rb" -e "TestClass.new.test_function 'hi'"
```

Comment: +1 :). Also. CamelCase for methods and variable names are non-Ruby style. Use undersore: `test_function`, `some_var`

Comment: See [reply by @lunero](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37948278/1245614) for multiple parameters

Answer (score 17):

Here's another variation, if you find that typing Ruby syntax at the command line is awkward and you really just want to pass arguments to Ruby. Here's *test.rb*:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

class TestClass
  def self.test_function(some_var)
    puts "I got the following variable: #{some_var}"
  end
end

TestClass.test_function(ARGV[0])
```

Make *test.rb* executable and run it like this:

```
./test.rb "Some Value"
```

Or run it like this:

```
ruby test.rb "Some Value"
```

This works because Ruby automatically sets the `ARGV` array to the arguments passed to the script. You could use `ARGV[0]` or `ARGV.first` to get the first argument, or you could combine the args into a single string, separated by spaces, using `ARGV.join(' ')`.

If you're doing lots of command-line stuff, you may eventually have a use for [Shellwords](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/shellwords/rdoc/Shellwords.html), which is in the standard Ruby library.

Comment: Usually you'd wrap the top-level code into `if __FILE__ == $0`.

Answer (score 6):

If you have multiple arguments to call in a example like this:

```
class TestClass
  def self.test_function(some_var1, some_var2)
    puts "I got the following variables: #{some_var1}, #{some_var2}"
  end
end
```

run it like this (the arguments need to be comma separated in this case)

```
ruby -r "./test.rb" -e "TestClass.new.test_function 'hi','Mike'"
```

Comment: this is great because initial answer did not cover 2 arguments.

Answer (score 3):

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

class A
  def run
    p :Hello_world
  end
  self
end.new.run
```

The usual way to script Ruby is to just use the *top level execution environment* called *main.* You can just start defining methods and code you write outside of a class, and these will be executed directly. (BTW, code inside a class but outside any method will run "by itself" also.)

Anyway, I'm with you ... I like writing all code in a named class and instantiating that class, so you can combine the techniques .. have the class return its own object .. and then use just a little of that top level code to allocate, initialize, and then dot into the class.

With this, you can just type `$ ruby test.rb` and it will do what you want.  Or you can `chmod +x test.rb; ./test.rb` since we did [add a shebang.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29)

Answer (score 2):

If you are working on a command line interface, then I would suggest to have a look at [thor](https://github.com/wycats/thor).

Thor directly maps your commands to methods within the defined class, see the [thor wiki](https://github.com/wycats/thor/wiki/Getting-Started) for an example.

Answer (score 2):

Just an extension to Ingenu's answer for the case that the function does not print something out, but does return something.

We would have the following *test.rb*

```
class TestClass
    def self.test_function(some_var)
        return "I got the following variable: " + some_var
    end
end
```

Then to invoke that from the command line and get the return value:

```
ruby -r "./test.rb" -e "puts TestClass.test_function('hi')"
```

Comment: There isn't anyone by the name "Ingenu" here. What answer does it refer to? [Candide's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10316495/call-a-ruby-function-from-the-command-line/10316711#10316711)?

Answer (score 2):

If you know that how to call an rb file from commandline

`ruby yourfile.rb`

This can do the whole trick for you.

What you have done is, just defined your methods in the class. Now you can call it below the definition. If you still want to read, wide open your eyes

```
class TestClass
  def self.test_function(some_var)
    puts "I got the following variable: #{some_var}"
  end
  test_function(var)
end
```